# Dark smudge at the TLC solvent front

Tags: chromatography, fluorescence

I have recently started using TLC in my graduate work to test for the cleavage of a cyclic oligo-adenylate in an enzymatic reaction. The sample I'm spotting on my plate is in an aqueous solution buffered with 25mM Tris. I am using a 20x20cm fluorescent silica plate as my stationary phase and my mobile phase is 20mM Ammonium Bicarbonate in 30% water and 70% ethanol. I am allowing the migration of the solvent to occur at room temperature in a chamber pre-equillibrated with the running buffer (The running buffer was added to the chamber and allowed to sit for > 1.0 h to maximize the vapor content of the chamber). These conditions are consistent with the literature that I have read dealing with cyclic oligo-adenylates.

I am visualizing my plate with a short-wavelength (254nm) UV lamp that causes the plate to fluoresce and analytes cast shadows. When I visualize my plate I see shadows for some of my analytes, but I also have a fat band at the solvent front (see attached photo). My questions are:

1. Is this dark band a problem? I don't think it is obscuring anything important, but I would feel more confident if it wasn't there.
2. Any ideas about what could be causing this band?

3.Any suggestions about getting rid of the band?

Like I said, I am pretty new to this whole TLC thing so I would be extremely grateful for any assistance.

[image]

Comment: Your mobile phase is too strong and the analytes (solutes) are traveling with the solvent. In other words, Rf is almost 1 and there is no retention on the plate for most of the solutes in your mixture.

Comment: The dark smudge are the major sample component spots, all joined together in a line. You want it to have RF somewhere in interval 0.3 - 0.7 for better spotting impurities/side products.  Your stationary phase may be too little active. Try temperate it in an oven at 105-120 Deg V to get lower Rf. Alternative is experimenting with increasing ethanol content in mobile phase.

Comment: Or you just have only a major component. But anyway seems that you have a too strong eluent / not enough active plate indeed. What I think you took wrong is the fact that you consider the most intense spots as an annoyance while (hopefully) they are the major component(s).